# PHP registration and login forms&email verification/Mail server setup

Tags: php, sql, wamp, mail-server

I'm working on a small website which requires users to signup for an account, after which an email is sent to them with details to verify the account. After clicking on the link in the verification email, the account should be active and the user should be able to login.
I have provided 3 PHP snippets from registration.php(to register), login.php(to login) and verify.php (to verify the activation of the account)
!! I'm using WAMP server to create the database and according table

NOTE: This is the only error I receive on the registration page.

Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\ONLINE BANKING\registration.php on line 541

Currently I have a few problems:
1. I am using the hmailserver, but I'm not exactly sure how to set it up 
2. I need to monitor when the users have been added to the database (I assume this is only after the email verification link is clicked)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how this can be fixed

```
**REGISTRATION.PHP**

     <div id="wrap">
                <!-- start PHP code -->
                <?php

                    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with root .
                    mysql_select_db("registrations") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

                    $email="";

                    if( isset($_POST['fullname']) // Is the name field being posted; it does not matter whether it's empty or filled.  
            && // This is the same as the AND in our statement; it allows you to check multiple statements.  
            !empty($_POST['fullname']) // Verify if the field name is not empty 
            AND isset($_POST['email']) // Is the email field being posted; it does not matter if it's empty or filled.  
            && // This is the same as the AND in our statement; it allows you to check multiple statements.  
            !empty($_POST['email']) ) // Verify if the field email is not empty   
              {

                        $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
                        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

                        }
                        if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)){
                            // Return Error - Invalid Email
                            $msg = 'The email you have entered is invalid, please try again.';
                        }else{
                            // Return Success - Valid Email
                            $msg = 'Your account has been created, <br /> please verify it by clicking the activation link that has been send to your email.';
                            }

                            $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) ); // Generate random 32 character hash and assign it to a local variable.

                            $PIN = rand(1000,5000); // Generate random number between 1000 and 5000 and assign it to a local variable.

        $to      = $email; // Send email to our user  
        $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; // Give the email a subject  
        $from="info@bfs.com";
        $message = 'Thanks for signing up! 
        Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by clicking the url below. 
        ------------------------ 
        echo $_POST["UserID"];
        PIN: '.$PIN.' 
        ------------------------ 
        Please click this link to activate your account: 
        http://www.yourwebsite.com/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.' 
        '; // Our message above including the link  
        $headers = 'From:noreply@yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers  
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email  //Line 541

                ?>
                <!-- stop PHP Code -->   


            </div>

**LOGIN.PHP**
<div id="wrap">
        <!-- start PHP code -->
        <?php

            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with UserID and PIN.
            mysql_select_db("registrations") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registration database.

            if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) AND isset($_POST['PIN']) && !empty($_POST['PIN'])){
                $UserID = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
                $PIN = mysql_escape_string(md5($_POST['PIN']));

                $search = mysql_query("SELECT UserID, PIN, active FROM users WHERE UserID='".$UserID."' AND PIN='".$PIN."' AND active='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
                $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);

                if($match > 0){
                    $msg = 'Login Complete! Thanks';
                }else{
                    $msg = 'Login Failed!<br /> Please make sure that you enter the correct details and that you have activated your account.';
                }
            }


        ?>
        <!-- stop PHP Code -->
        <?php 
            if(isset($msg)){ // Check if $msg is not empty
                echo '<div class="statusmsg">'.$msg.'</div>'; // Display our message and add a div around it with the class statusmsg
            } ?>

    </div>

**VERIFY.PHP**
```

Answer (score 3):

You must setup your server for sendig mail

```
set mail function in php.ini file to sendmail_path ="\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" if you use something like xampp
and then
set senmail.ini
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com //example

smtp_port=587
auth_username=YourMail@gmail.com
auth_password=YourMailPass
```

In your case you have wamp server and you should configure this server for sending mail as i stated example for xampp

Answer (score 1):

I suggest if you already have a web hosting account, you can simply try it online using your Gmail or Yahoo a/c. Setting up Email on the desktop is hectic and time consuming.

Comment: I already have a web hosting account. But how do I go about testing that when the user registers the email is sent say from my yahoo email to whatever email address the user has specified in the registration page?

Comment: It's a long process! Kindly check this example on this link and you'll be ready to go. http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/24.html

Comment: Thanks, that's a very helpful link. I'm assuming that there's nothing wrong with my code up to this point. (The only difference is that in the link you gave me, there is a temporary database where registration details are stored and transferred after the link in the verification email is clicked.) I basically just need to know if the way I'm going about it is correct as well as effective

Comment: No, you're not doing it right. There should be 2 tables for temporary users and another for members who have actually confirmed their email address. This is a perfect way to go about.

Answer (score 0):

Create Your web pages contains (Login page , registration page and  main Page) with requirements:

1- apply a validation on registration form of username, email, password, re-type password, gender and birthdate data.

2- verification to login form data with username & password and create Login session.

3- a database connection establish to store users information and verify login data.

4- restriction to main page and access granted only if login success.

5- logout from main page and destroy user session.

moyasar_22@hotmail.com